# PHP: json_encode() does not work

Tags: php, json

Why my code doesn´t works?. I have another one with the same code and it works!. I dont know what´s the problem with this one.

```
<?php
include("../conexion.php");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
    $query = 'SELECT Id, Nombre, Descripcion FROM empresa ORDER BY Nombre';
    $sql = mysql_query($query, $link);
    mysql_close($link);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $myEnterprises[] = array(
        'Id' => $row['Id'],
        'Nombre' => $row['Nombre'],
        'Descripcion' => $row['Descripcion']);
    }
    $myData = array('myEnterprises' => $myEnterprises);
    echo json_encode($myData);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you check if `$myData` is an array or something that can be JSON encoded?

Comment: what is the `json_encode` output ? because we are clueless!! :)

Comment: What means "*doesn't work*"? Wrong output, no output, errors? Are you sure that the if clause is actually true?

Comment: try running it in jsonlint.com (the output, that is)...

Comment: check in ajax success callback. What's the error you are getting

Comment: i think this is `mysql_close` before `mysql_fetch_array`, try put `mysql_close` before `echo json_encode($myData)`;

Comment: "doesn´t work" means i dont get any response and print_r($mydata); before the json_encode show me the structure of the array

Answer (score 0):

```
(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0)
json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value
```

This is the minimum requirement for running json_encode() in your server. Check your PHP version. If the PHP version is less than 5.2.0 ,follow [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?2362-Getting-the-JSON-examples-to-work-on-PHP4.x) link for implementation of json_encode in your server / php application .